# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC with SUM() not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Why doesn't this work?

```
$selectAllCount = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(`count`) FROM `Test_Table`");
$selectAllCount->execute();

while($allCountRow = $selectAllCount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $allCountRow['count'];
}
```

I have tried many other methods with mysql_libs and none of them seem to work, what's wrong here?

Comment: Do a `print_r($allCountRow)` inside your loop and you'll see exactly what's wrong

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to give the column a name:

```
$selectAllCount = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(`count`) as count FROM `Test_Table`");
```

Now you'll be able to fetch the result as you wanted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the best way:

```
$selectAllCount = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(`count`) FROM `Test_Table`");
$selectAllCount->execute();
$count = $selectAllCount->fetchColumn(0);
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php